# some confusion regarding convergent of $ f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

i found question here : [Convergence of integral doesn't imply the uniform convergence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814242/convergence-of-integral-doesnt-imply-the-uniform-convergence)

But i didn't understand the  answer fully.

Is there  any  other  answer  so that i can understand ?

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $f$ be integrable functions on $[0, 1]$ such that
>   $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1|f_n(x) - f(x)| dx = 0$ then $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for almost everywhere $x \in [0,1]$

My attempt :  i read the  answer  but i didn't understand

[image]

Any other easy  answer ?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? The function $f$ is taken as $0$ because it's an example that works, and it should be easy to compute each $\int_0^1 |f_n|$.

Comment: Directly, $\int_0^1 |f_1|= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$.  $\int_0^1 |f_2|= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$.  $\int_0^1 |f_3|= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}$. $\int_0^1 |f_4|= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \dots$  Now note that $f_n \not\to 0$ pointwise.  For example, the sequence $f_n(1/2)$ oscillates.

Comment: If you take $f(x) = 0$, then $\int_0^1 |f_n(x)  - f(x)|\,dx$ is simply $\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|\,dx$.  So if you can show that the latter goes to zero, you will have shown that $f_n$ satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: @Dzoooks that mean $ \int_{0}^{1}|f_n| = 1.1/n \int_{0}^{1}|f_{n-1}|$

Comment: @NateEldredge my  confusion is  about  $f_1, f_2, ......f_n$ i mean  they have different value  which contain $0$ and $1$ so  how  i can calculate $f_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** Formally, let $g_n=f_n-f$ and $g=0$.

Then,  $g_n$ and $g=0$ are integrable functions on $[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int |g_n(x)-g(x)|dx=0$, and you need to show that then$g_n(x) \to g(x)$ for almost everywhere $x\in[0,1]$.

This way, you reduce the problem to exactly the same one, but with $g=0$.

**Q2:** Since $g(x)=0$ you have $\int |g_n(x)-g(x)|dx=\int |g_n(x)|dx$

Or, if you are asking why does that particular integral go to zero, note that for

- $1 \leq  n\leq 2$ we have $\int |f_n| =\frac{1}{2}$.
- $3 \leq n \leq 6$ we have $\int |f_n| =\frac{1}{4}$.
- $7 \leq n \leq 14$ we have $\int |f_n| =\frac{1}{8}$.
  ...
- $2^{m}-1 \leq n \leq 2^{m+1}-2$ we have $\int |f_n| =\frac{1}{2^m}$.

Comment: thanks u @N.S  but im not getting ur   sequence  function my confusion is  that when $1\le n \le  2$  we have $\int_{0}^{1}f_n= \int_{0}^{1/2} f_1 + \int_{1/2}^{1} f_2 = 1/2 +  (1-1/2)=1$

Comment: @jasmine $\int_0^1 f_n$ means a FIXED index, not two of them. For example, $\int_0^1 f_1= \int_0^\frac{1}{2} 1 d x =\frac{1}{2}$ and $\int_0^1 f_2 =\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 1 dx=\frac{1}{2}$. You are adding the first two integrals together.

Comment: .@ N.S thanks  u now  got its

Comment: one last doubt @N.S why $f_n(x)$ is not tend to  $0$  almost everywhere  $x\in [0,1]$? i mean why $f_n $ is not almost everywhere ?

Comment: @jasmine Each $f_n$ is 1 on a set of positive measure. And for each $x \in [0,1]$ you can find arbitrarily large $n$ such that $f_n(x)$ is 0 and arbitrarily larghe for which it is 1.