# some confusion regarding convergent of function $f_n$

Tags: real-analysis

From my previous question :[Yes/No Is $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for almost everywhere $x \in [0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375036/yes-no-is-f-nx-rightarrow-fx-as-n-rightarrow-infty-for-almost-everyw)

## I know that $f_n \rightarrow  0$ almost everwhere mean where function not going to  $0$ and measure  is $0$ in $[0,1]$

> Take $n=2^k+m$, where $m,k\in\mathbb{Z}_+, 0\leq m<2^k$. Let $I_n=\left[\frac{k}{2^m}, \frac{k+1}{2^m}\right]$. Let
>
> $f_n(x)= \begin{cases}1 \ \text{if}  \ x\in I_n,\\ 0 \ \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$
>
> Then $\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx=\frac1{2^k} \to 0$,

My question is that in my previous question it said that  $f_n(x)$ doesnot converge to $0$ for almost everywhere  $ x \in [0,1]$. Why ?

My thinking is that $f_n(x)$  is converege  to $0 $ almost everywhere  except  for uncountable set (it has not measure $0$)

Comment: Do you mean $I_n=\left[\frac{m}{2^k}, \frac{m+1}{2^k}\right]$?

Comment: ya  right @Arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f_n(0) = 1$ whenever $n = 2^k$ (and $0$ otherwise). Similarily, $f_n(\frac12) = 1$ whenever $n = 2^k + 2^{k-1}$ or $n = 2^k + 2^{k-1} - 1$ (and $0$ otherwise).

More generally, for any $x$, there are *infinitely* many values of $n$ for which $f_n(x) = 1$, and infinitely many values of $n$ for which $f_n(x) = 0$. This means $f_n$ doesn't converge *anywhere*, regardless of what happens to the integral.

Comment: thanks u @Arthur  one more  doubt  if  $I_n$ is  finite  take  $n= 4$ i mean $ I_4$ then $f_n $will converge to $0$  almost  everywhere  .Is it right ??

Comment: @jasmine That's unclear. What would $f_5$ be in that case? What about $f_6$ or $f_7$, and so on? You can't can't ask about convergence and you can't have a limit unless you have an infinite sequence first.